# Select function for multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse, lapply

I have 9 data frames and I would like to the same columns from all of them, so one of them looks like this:

```
    > str(ess2002)
tibble [39,334 × 566] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ name    : chr [1:39334] "ESS1e06_6" "ESS1e06_6" "ESS1e06_6" "ESS1e06_6" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Title of dataset"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%9s"
 $ essround: num [1:39334] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "ESS round"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%12.0g"
 $ edition : chr [1:39334] "6.6" "6.6" "6.6" "6.6" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Edition"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%3s"
 $ proddate: chr [1:39334] "01.12.2018" "01.12.2018" "01.12.2018" "01.12.2018" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Production date"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%10s"
 $ cntry   : chr [1:39334] "AT" "AT" "AT" "AT" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Country"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%2s"
 $ idno    : num [1:39334] 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 10 12 14 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Respondent's identification number"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%12.0g"
```

I want to select variables that start with "prtvt", variables that contain "IM", "QFIM" or "RFG". And to do that for each of the nine dataframes.
I tried to create a list with all dataframes and to run an lapply with the select function, like this:

```
df.list <- list(ess2002,ess2004,ess2006,ess2008,
            ess2010,ess2012,ess2014,ess2016, ess2018)
lapply(df.list, select(starts_with("prtvt") | contain(c("IM", "QFIM", "RFG"))))
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: `starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code

```
df.list <- list(ess2002,ess2004,ess2006,ess2008,
            ess2010,ess2012,ess2014,ess2016, ess2018)
lapply(
  1:length(df.list), 
  function(x) {
    df.list[[x]] %>% 
      select(
        starts_with("prtvt"), 
        contains(c("IM", "QFIM", "RFG"))
      )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try `purrr`'s `map` function

```
library(tidyverse)
df.list %>% 
  map(., ~select(.,starts_with("prtvt") | contains(c("IM", "QFIM","RFG"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

For your `lapply()` statement you need to use an anonymous function within `lapply()`, or to not use the parentheses and provide arguments to `select()`.

**Anonymous function**:

Here `df`--declared in the anonymous function--represent each element of `df.list`

```
lapply(df.list, function(df) select(df, starts_with("prtvt"), contains(c("IM", "QFIM", "RFG"))))

# or lapply(df.list, function(x) select(x, starts_with("prtvt"), contains(c("IM", "QFIM", "RFG"))))
```

**Provide arguments to your function (`select()`)**

Here the first non-named argument to your function is each element of `df.list`. In this case, each element of `df.list` goes in the first position of `select()`:

```
lapply(df.list, select, starts_with("prtvt"), contains(c("IM", "QFIM", "RFG")))
```

Alternatively, if you prefer a **base R solution**, you can use this:

```
lapply(df.list, function(x) x[startsWith(names(x), "prtvt") | grepl("IM|QFIM|RFG", names(x))])

# or lapply(df.list, function(x) x[grepl("^prtvt|IM|QFIM|RFG)", names(x))])
```